# Missing host name in links after upgrade to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading my application to Rails 5.0 all my links complain in production mode about:

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

I have two other applications running Rails 5.x without problems and without having set any default host url, except for the mailers.

The request.env parameters do show HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME parameters. All links render within controller environment and basic HTML views.

Any clue where to look for?

Comment: Does 5.1 also exhibit this problem? Is that an option for you?

Comment: I'm willing to try upgrading to Rails 5.1 to see if that solves the problem. Due to deprecation messages an upgrade path including 5.0 would be more convenient.

Comment: It's worth doing as a quick test even if you need to upgrade more incrementally.

Comment: Are you talking about all links, not just in mailers?

Comment: Especially the 'normal' links, not the mailers as they read the default_url_options on ActionMailer::Base.

Comment: I will try upgrading to rails 5.1 tomorrow.